# How to indicate a parameter that "include trait" in PHPDoc

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Recently I ran into an interesting situation when implementing a PHP application using PhpStorm. The following code snippet illustrates the problem.

```
    interface I{
        function foo();
    }

    trait T{
        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTraitMsg()
        {
            return "I am a trait";
        }
    }

    class A implements I{
        use T;
        function foo(){}
    }

    class C implements I{
        use T;
        function foo(){}
    }

    class B {
        /**
         * @param I $input <===Is there anyway to specify that $input use T? 
         */
        public function doSomethingCool($input){ //An instance of "A" or "C"
           $msg = $input -> getTraitMsg();  //Phpstorm freaks out here
        }
    }
```

My question is in the comment. How do I indicate that `$input` parameter implements `I` and uses `T`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a lit bit hackly, but you can use `class_uses` it returns list of used traits. And add `T` as a @param type in PHPDoc for autocomplete

```
class B {
    /**
     * @param I|T $input <===Is there anyway to specify that $input use T?
     */
    public function doSomethingCool($input){ //An instance of "A" or "C"
        $uses = class_uses(get_class($input));
        if (!empty($uses['T'])) {
            echo $input->getTraitMsg();  //Phpstorm freaks out here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you cannot type hint a trait usage in such way (`@param` only accepts scalar types or classes/interfaces + some [keywords](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#keyword)).

**The ideal solution** for you would be placing `getTraitMsg()` declaration into `I` interface.

If this cannot be done .. then you can specify that only instances of `A` or `C` can be passed here (as they utilize that trait):

```
/**
 * @param A|C $input
 */
public function doSomethingCool($input)
{
    $msg = $input->getTraitMsg();  // PhpStorm is good now
}
```

If names of such possible classes are unknown in advance (e.g. it's a library code and final classes could be anything in every new project or even added in current project at any time) .. then I suggest to **use safeguards**, which you should be using with such code anyway (via `method_exists()`):

```
/**
 * @param I $input
 */
public function doSomethingCool($input)
{
    if (method_exists($input, 'getTraitMsg')) {
        $msg = $input->getTraitMsg();  // PhpStorm is good now
    }
}
```

Why use safeguard? Because you may pass instance of another class `K` that implements `I` but does not use trait `T`. In such case code without guard will break.

---

Just to clarify: you could use `@param I|T $input` to specify that method expects instance that implements `I` or uses `T` .. but it's only works for PhpStorm (not sure about other IDEs) -- AFAIK it's not accepted by actual PHPDocumentor and does not seem to fit the PHPDoc [proposed standard](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md).

Answer (score 0):

*"//Phpstorm freaks out here"* -- no, it's not. It just tries to signal you that your code is not correct.

The contract of method `doSomethingCool()` doesn't require `$input` to expose any method named `getTraitMsg()`. The docblock says it should implement `interface I` but the docblock is not code, it only helps PhpStorm help you with validations and suggestions.

Because you didn't type-hinted the argument `$input`, the code:

```
$b = new B();
$b->doSomethingCool(1);
```

is valid but it crashes as soon as it tries to execute the line `$msg = $input -> getTraitMsg();`.

If you want to call `getTraitMsg()` on `$input` you have to:

- declare the type of `$input`;
- make sure the declared type of `$input` exposes a method named `getTraitMsg()`.

For the first step, your existing code of class `B` should read:

```
class B {
    /**
     * @param I $input 
     */
    public function doSomethingCool(I $input) {
       $msg = $input -> getTraitMsg();
    }
}
```

Please remark the type `I` in front of argument `$input` in the parameters list.

The easiest way to accomplish the next step is to declare method `getTraitMsg()` into the `interface I`:

```
interface I {
    function foo();
    function getTraitMsg();
}
```

Now, the code:

```
$b = new B();
$b->doSomethingCool(1);
```

throws an exception when it reaches the line `$b->doSomethingCool(1);` (i.e. before entering the function). It is the PHP's way to tell you the method is not invoked with the correct arguments. You have to pass it an object that implements the `interface I`, no matter if it is of type `A` or `C`. It can be of any other type that implements `interface I` and nobody cares if it uses `trait T` to implement it or not.